# Why is the JsonObject in the Facebook SDK (v6.0.10-beta) hidden?

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone

I am using this new SDK and the JsonObject class seems to be hidden. The FacebookApiEventArgs has a result object of type "object", but the instance type is JsonObject which is not available in intellisense...

Any idea why this is designed in such a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly discouraged to use `JsonObject` or `JsonArray`. Use `IDictionary<string,object>` or `IList<object>` instead.

JsonObject and JsonArray will continue to work, but has been hidden from intellisense.

Comment: Thanks... That seems a little weird - to have to cast to that everytime I want to access it, or have to write an extension method.

Comment: Actually.. Just to make sure I understand.. The expecation of the SDK is that, when passing in parameters, users create an object implementing one of these 2 interfaces and pass them in? Just to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: you don't need to implement those interfaces, you can pass the general .net framework types such as Dictionary<string,object> or ExpandoObject or even anonymous types as parameters. http://csharpsdk.org/docs/making-synchronous-requests.html

Comment: I am using WP7 - no expandos. It's not a big deal. It just seemed like a strage design decision to me. Thanks for the info, again.